# Pass Variable to .animate Step Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, jquery-animate

Run into a wall while trying to pass a variable into my step function to handle some final cross browser fallback animation. I've built a general purpose animation method here:

```
Animator:function(obj,aniArgs,duration,aniEasArgs,delay,stepFunction,completeFunction){
    obj.stop(true,true).animate(aniArgs,
        {duration:parseInt(duration,10),queue:false,specialEasing:aniEasArgs,
         step:function(now,fx){     
        if($.isFunction(stepFunction)){ 
                     stepFunction.apply(this,arguments); 
        };      
     },complete:function(){
        if($.isFunction(completeFunction)){   
                     completeFunction.apply(this,arguments); };}});
         };
}
```

This works and animates everything needed. However I'm attempting to call the Animator function and use the step function to animate a property. Here's the call:

```
var angle=0,            
    stepFunction=function(now,fx,angle){
    angle+=1;
        $(this).css({"-ms-transform":"rotate("+angle+"deg)"});
    };

Animator(obj,aniArgs,speed,easing,0,stepFunction,null);
```

All of the other arguments being passed in are fine and check out well. The obj is the obj being animated, aniArgs is an object literal containing all CSS names/values to animate, speed is speed, easing is an object literal containing all CSS names/easing values, the stepFunction is the function variable declared above, and null is indicating there isn't a complete function to execute.

Everything is working great, but I'm running into a variable issue with the step function. I can't seem to get the value of angle inside of the actual step function. Inside the step, I can log now and fx, and those are working well, however I'm unable to pass in the angle with the initial 0 value so that I can increment it.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try removing `angle` from the list of arguments for `stepFunction`, for example `stepFunction=function(now,fx){...`.  This should result in `angle` from the containing scope being used, but I'm not confident enough in my js to know for sure if it will work.

Comment: Nope, originally tried that. Angle needs to be defined at 0 first, then passed into the step function as 0 for the counter to work correctly during the animation.

Comment: @F.J, that will run though it's probably not what's required, the reason being that a step function is called at unknown intervals and an unknown number of times within the animation duration. I think it will be necessary to calculate the rotation afresh from `now` at each step.

Comment: `window.angle` inside the callback?

Comment: That is simply not possible like that. There are many alternatives, but you seem to be trying to rotate an element and that's not the right way to do it. The tick time between each call is not necessarily constant and adding to the `angle` variable a constant value will make your animation looks wrong. You need to use the `now` as a factor to calculate the current angle inside the step function at each call.

Comment: I'd like to avoid global variables if possible. @FJ, not sure what you mean by calculating the rotation afresh? If you mean base the rotation animation off of the now number, there's an object of properties being passed to .animate, so now can get erratic

Comment: @Diego, ok. How can i normalize the now variable to work when animating multiple properties? When I log now it's jumping all over the place

Comment: @AAron I posted an answer with an example. Inside that you can use the same logic of `start +(range *now)` for each value you want to animate. Of course the `range` and `start` values will be different for each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. . As @Beetroot-Beetroot said seconds before I finished typing my comment, the time between each call for the `progress function` is not necessarily constant and adding a constant value to the `angle` variable will make your animation looks wrong.

. . The `step` event, as per [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), is called possibly more than once per tick per property and uses a set of parameters that are not really useful in this case. We were commenting about the `progress` callback all the time, but using the wrong name. I'm not sure if jQuery changed it's implementation (it seems like the `progress` function was added on v1.8), but I had this "step" name in my mind for some reason. I think the incredible [GreenSock's tweening library](https://www.greensock.com/) uses the "step" name as well. Anyway, in jQuery, the signatures for `step` and `progress` are as follow:

**step: function (Number now, Tween tween):** the first parameter is *the value* of one property being animated and the second is *the jQuery's tween object* (that includes the `prop` property so you know which property the `now` value refers to).

**progress: function (Promise animation, Number progress, Number remainingMs):** the first parameter is [a jQuery promise object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise) representing the animation, the second parameter is a number from 0 to 1 representing the percentage of the animation's progress and the third parameter is the number of miliseconds until the animation ends.

. . For your purpose the `progress` event is clearly what you need. Remember to change the `step` property to `progress` in the object you pass to `jQuery.animate` in your `Animator` function..

. . You need to use the `progress` value (as it's a value between 0 and 1 indicating the percentage of the animation progress) as a factor to calculate the current angle inside the `progress function` at each call:

```
progressFunction = function(animation, progress, lastingms) {
  var startAngle = 0, endAngle = 180;
  var angleRange = endAngle -startAngle;
  var curAngle = startAngle +(angleRange *progress);
  $(this).css({"-ms-transform":"rotate("+ curAngle +"deg)"});
};
```

. . Whenever you need more values to animate, use the same logic:

```
progressFunction = function(animation, progress, lastingms) {
  var startA = 0, endA = 180, rangeA = (endA -startA);
  var startX = 254, endX = 894, rangeX = (endX -startX);

  var curA = startA + rangeA *progress;
  var curX = startX + rangeX *progress;
  $(this).css({
    "-ms-transform":"rotate("+ curAngle +"deg)",
    'left': curX +'px'
  });
};
```

. . It makes sense to try to make it somehow more automatic if you plan to use it as a lib in many parts of your code so that you don't need to keep writing this same logic all around.

Comment: This works out ok, except the ending angles aren't right. But I think it's a good start to work with. Thanks a ton Diego! :)

Comment: @Aaron I'm not really sure how the `step` function works in jQuery, but you may need to call this function one last time on the `onComplete` event with a `now` value of `1` if jQuery doesn't call the `step` before that already.

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, with a little tweaking this will do it :)

Comment: @Aaron, sorry my memory let me down. With reference to the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), you want to be using the `progress` option (available from jQuery 1.8) instead of `step`. The `progress` handler takes the following arguments, `function( animation, progress, remainingMs )`, where `progress` gives the value you want to work with, ranging from 0 to 1 as the animation progresses.

Comment: Awesome, first time I've seen that :) will definitely check it out since the step function isn't quite working as well as I'd like it to.

Comment: @Beetroot, the progress function is SOOOOO much better than the step function. It worked perfectly :)

Comment: That's cool Aaron. Diego, maybe you could edit your answer to reflect `progress` in lieu of `step` and `now`.

Comment: My answer actually doesn't use any of them. I didn't reproduce the part of jQuery code that handles this, but I will rename the function in my example so that it may become obvious that it is best to use "progress".

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the step function are fixed by the animation infrastructure - you can't add arguments to it as it is called by the infrastructure with a fixed set of arguments.  You could make a stub function (kind of like you did) and add arguments and then call your own function.

```
Animator:function(obj,aniArgs,duration,aniEasArgs,delay,stepFunction,completeFunction){
    // initialize angle
    var angle = 0;
    obj.stop(true,true).animate(aniArgs,
        {duration:parseInt(duration,10),queue:false,specialEasing:aniEasArgs,
         step:function(now,fx){     
        if($.isFunction(stepFunction)){ 
                     // convert these args into an array
                     var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
                     // add angle onto existing arguments
                     args.push(angle);
                     // call the stepFunction with new arg added on to the end
                     stepFunction.apply(this,args); 
        };      
     },complete:function(){
        if($.isFunction(completeFunction)){   
                     completeFunction.apply(this,arguments); };}});
         };
}
```

Or, you can use `.data()` on the object begin animated to store any variable for the duration of the animation.  Set the angle on the object before you start the animation and you should be able to access it and update it from within the step function by referencing `$(this).data()`.

This keeps you from having to use global variables and supports animating multiple objects at the same time.

As others have pointed out, a good animation calculates the next position each time based on the elapsed time, not on the number of times the step function has been called.  This allows you to stay on-time even if the animation happens to fall behind a little bit due to other things going on in the browser.

Comment: Great workaround idea, but Diego has provide a good solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @Aaron - it looks like you have a solution now, but see the code example I added to actually add arguments to your stepFunction.